# How to use Ansible to update a client machine without having its IP address

Tags: ansible, iot

Ansbile can be used to update a machine via ssh, and in order to establish such connection, you need an accessible IP address.

How to use it to update a fleet of distributed machines on different networks (consumers) which don't have a public address?
One solution I was thinking of, is to reverse the procedure, have Ansible configured on the client machine, that connects each day to the server, read a file to see if it has a new update for it and loads that update.

I find this not straightforward, is there another way?

Comment: You have tagged [puppet], but this question seems to have nothing to do with Puppet, unless, perhaps, that the desired mode of operation you describe is analogous to Puppet's.

Answer (score 1):

[ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html) is exacly what you are looking for.